# Why does onClick prop return undefined on first click?

Tags: reactjs

As in object, I'm writing a React app, but cannot figure out why when I click on the card, the first click returns undefined, and then the next click returns the element I clicked on before that. I leave my code here.

**app.js** calls the main component (I want to make the app component as functional as possible).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Main from './components/MainComponent';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className='App'>
        <Main />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**MainComponent.js** contains everything logic related (it is still at a very early stage)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Icon } from 'react-materialize';

import Dashboard from './DashboardComponent';
import Details from './DetailsComponent';

import { ITEMS } from '../shared/items';
import { SUPPLIERS } from '../shared/suppliers';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: ITEMS,
            suppliers: SUPPLIERS,
            selectedItem: null
        };
        this.onItemSelect = this.onItemSelect.bind(this);
    }

    onItemSelect(itemId) {
        this.setState({ selectedItem: itemId });
        console.log(this.state.items.filter(item => item.id === this.state.selectedItem)[0]);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.state.selectedItem);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Navbar
                    alignLinks='right'
                    menuIcon={<Icon>menu</Icon>}
                    fixed
                    className='green'
                    search
                >
                </Navbar>
                <Dashboard items={this.state.items} onClick={(itemId) => this.onItemSelect(itemId)} />
                <Details item={this.state.items.filter(item => item.id === this.state.selectedItem)[0]} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

**DashboardComponent.js** this is where the problem occurs. Whenever I reload the page, if item is null (which is supposed to be), I get an error of it being undefined. If in the main component I hard code the selected item to be one of the ids (which is a field of items), I get that if I click on a card, I get undefined back. Then if I click on another card, I get back the informations of the one I clicked before that.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Icon, Card, CardTitle, Container } from 'react-materialize';

class Dashboard extends Component {
    render() {
        const dashboard = this.props.items.map(item => {
            return (
                <div key={item.id}>
                    <Col m={6} s={12}>
                        <Card
                            actions={[
                                <a key={item.id} href='#'>Details</a>
                            ]}
                            onClick={() => this.props.onClick(item.id)}
                            closeIcon={<Icon>close</Icon>}
                            header={<CardTitle image="https://materializecss.com/images/sample-1.jpg" />}
                            horizontal
                            revealIcon={<Icon>more_vert</Icon>}
                            title={item.name}
                            >
                                
                            </Card>
                    </Col>
                </div>
            );
        });

        return(
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    {dashboard}
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

**DetailsComponent.js** is what is supposed to be shown when I click on a card. But, as mentioned before, I can't understand why.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Col, Card, CardTitle, Icon, Row, Container } from 'react-materialize';

class Details extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    renderItem(item) {
        switch (item) {
            case null:
                return (<div></div>);

            default:
                return (
                    <Col m={6} s={12}>
                        <Card
                            actions={[
                                <a key={item.id} href='/'>Details</a>
                            ]}
                            closeIcon={<Icon>close</Icon>}
                            header={<CardTitle image="https://materializecss.com/images/sample-1.jpg" />}     
                            revealIcon={<Icon>more_vert</Icon>}
                            title={item.name}
                        >
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                );
        }
    }

    renderDetails(item) {
        switch(item) {
            case null:
                return (<div></div>);
            
            default:
                return (
                <Col m={6} s={12}>
                    <p>{item.name}</p>
                    <p>{item.location}</p>
                    <p>{item.supplier}</p>
                    <p>{new Intl.DateTimeFormat('it-IT', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit', hour12: true, hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric' }).format(new Date(item.insertDate))}</p>
                    <p>{new Intl.DateTimeFormat('it-IT', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: '2-digit' }).format(new Date(item.purchaseDate))}</p>
                    <p>{(item.inUse).toString()}</p>
                    <p>{item.invoiceNumber}</p>
                </Col>
                );
        }   
    }
    
    render() {
        return(
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    {this.renderItem(this.props.item)}
                    {this.renderDetails(this.props.item)}
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default Details;
```

I know I put a lot of code, but if somebody could help me it would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think that you added the clonsole.log under the setState command. It's a bug. The state is not updated.

Comment: Move your console.log in the render method to see if your value really gets updated (it should). setState is async so if you console.log right after it you don't always get the updated value.

Comment: In fact, you are probably logging the old value every time... So even the second click is not the right value you want since setState is async. If your code is correct (seems to be) your value is updating correctly but you are console.logging too early. Move your console.log to the render method, you'll see a console.log every update but you should see the correct value when clicked.

Comment: Thank you both, but the console.log is actually the least of the problems. The biggest one is that if I put null as the initial state for selectedItem (which should be), the code does not work because everything is undefined. But since it's null, it should execute the case null in the switch statement; for some reason though, it does not and I can't figure out why